# How can I see the values of a variable that I specified with "size = " in a plotly plot using R (package: plotly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I want to produce an interactive plot using the plotly package in R. I want a scatter plot where each point is "sized" according to their continuous values. My plot does show the sized points, but it does not show me which value they are when I hover on them. The reproducible code:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = mtcars,
        x = ~ wt, y = ~ mpg, color = ~factor(cyl),
        mode = "markers", type = "scatter", size = ~hp)
Warning messages:
1: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values. 
2: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values. 
3: `line.width` does not currently support multiple values.
```

What I want is when I go to a specific point, I want to interactively see which "hp" value it has apart from its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this with `, text = ~hp` in to the plot_ly window and format it using [this link](https://plotly.com/r/hover-text-and-formatting/)

eg

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data = mtcars,
        x = ~ wt, y = ~ mpg, color = ~factor(cyl),
        mode = "markers", type = "scatter", size = ~hp, 
        text = ~hp, 
        hovertemplate = paste("Values: %{x}, %{y}<br>", 
                              "Size: %{text}")
)
```

[image]

Comment: this is very useful! could you please explain why does not show the numbers by default? for example I would like to know why when we set color = ~factor(cyl) we see the values without doing any additional coding unlike when we want to see the size = ~hp values? Also, I would also like to know what really happens inside of the paste(..) function

Comment: It's the default tooltip settings for plotly. You'd have to ask them why they decided only to include x and y by default :). I'd recommend reading through the examples in the link I attached. It follows through to the help page for hovertemplate: https://plotly.com/r/reference/#pie-hovertemplate that explains the syntax eg `%{x}` is the syntax code plotly uses to extract the x field in the plot_ly call. It's based from d3 formatting, as plot_ly is a javascript library built on top of d3.js

Comment: whoops i guess my question was not clear, sorry! I meant setting color = ~factor(cyl) will make the cyl values visible when we choose a point and it also gives us a nice legend indicating colors. However, when we set size = ~hp we do not get any of these and I wonder why.